# How to send data as json format via textinput array

Tags: react-native

I'm using paho mqtt. I want to sent the data to the client as json array via textinput but it seems like I'm getting undefined data

```
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
 listofItems: [],
    text: '',
    text1: '',
}}


_addTask () {
        const listofItems = [...this.state.listofItems, this.state.text, this.state.text1];

        this.setState({
            listofItems: listofItems,
            text: '',
            text1: '',
        });

        this._changeTextInputValue('');
    }

    _changeTextInputValue (text) {
        this.setState({
            text
        });
    }

    _changeTextInputValue1 (text1) {
        this.setState({
            text1
        });
    }

    static _renderRowData (rowData) {
        return (
            <Text>{ rowData }</Text>
        )
    }
```

And this is the text input

```
<TextInput autoCorrect={ false } 
  onChangeText={ (text) => this._changeTextInputValue(text) }
  onSubmitEditing = {() => this.itemcodeDesc.focus()}
  style={{backgroundColor:'#ddd'}}
  value={ this.state.text }
/>

<TextInput
 autoCorrect={ false }
 onChangeText={ (text1) => this._changeTextInputValue1(text1) }
 onSubmitEditing={ () => this._addTask() }
 returnKeyType={ 'done' }
 ref={(input) => this.itemcodeDesc = input}
 style={{backgroundColor:'#ddd'}}
 value={ this.state.text1 }
/>
```

And the button:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.sendMessage} underlayColor="transparent">
   <Text style={styles.buttonText}>NEXT</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

but I cant get the array of items in json format as I call this

```
"items": [{"itemcode":"'+this.state.listofItems[]+'"}]
```

in sendMessage function. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can anyone help me. I'm still having trouble with this one. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess its suppose to be `this.state.listofItems` rather then `this.state.listofItems[]`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for this but the output goes like this:

[{"item":"345,34,234,34"}]

is it possible to get something like this:

[{"item":"345", "itemdesc": "34"}, {"item":"234", "itemdesc": "34"}]

Comment: In that case your this.state.listofItems need to be formatted as object not as an Array and then pass this as JSON.toString(this.state.listofItems) to the same place

Comment: is it right that I change listofItems:[] to listofItems: {}

I got this output: [{"itemcode":"[object JSON]"}]

Comment: @kkumber, you need to stringify the JSON and pass it as argument